# Using DBeaver to query a PostgreSQL db and get following error: SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am completely new to SQL, PostgreSQL, and DBeaver. When trying to simply query a table from a database:

```
SELECT * FROM operation.fs.ten_q_score;
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "operation.fs.ten_q_score"¶  Position: 15
```

I have looked at the dblink, but do not even understand how to install something like dblink (even after looking at the actual documentation).

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Connect to the `operation` database, then run the query without the database name: `SELECT * FROM fs.ten_q_score;`

Comment: How do I connect to the operation db? Thanks!

Comment: The database is typically specified in the JDBC URL. I don't use DBeaver, so I can't tell you how it's done there

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add connection here

[image]

choose PostgreSQL and type in your connection:

[image]

finish setting up connection, connect to db and run

```
SELECT * FROM fs.ten_q_score;
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out a few hours (lol) after posting this question and this was the fix!

Answer (score 23):

Maybe it will help someone, if you have several connection then you have to right click on connection your are going to work with and `set it as active`, after that when you press `F3` button you will have an access to your currently selected database.

[image]

Comment: This one helps me. Thanks

Comment: OMG, this solved my issue. Till now I was avoiding dbeaver and using PGAdmin, as I had seen this error..